# Simulate random draws with a pdf function in R

Tags: r, simulation

I have got a (Gaussian) kernel density estimate of the following data:

```
x <- c(4.09, 4.46, 4.61, 4.30, 4.03, 5.22, 4.21, 4.07, 4.02, 4.58, 4.66, 4.05, 
       4.23, 5.51, 4.03, 4.72, 4.47, 4.50, 5.80, 4.30, 4.09, 4.78, 4.18, 4.45,
       4.40, 5.60, 4.37, 4.42, 4.88, 4.20, 4.45, 4.10, 4.43, 4.58, 4.40, 4.38)
h <- bw.nrd(x)
h

kde <- function(y) {
  1/36/h/sqrt(2*pi)*sum(exp(((y-x)/h)^2*-1/2))
}
```

I'm supposed to simulate 36 random draws from the kernel density estimate/pdf above. That is, the function kde in the code above is a pdf that I would like to sample from, ideally in the range 4.02 to 5.80, the range of the data, thirty six times. (But of course, we could just throw out results that are outside this range.) Of course, if I knew how to draw a random number from a pdf I could just write a for loop with 36 iterations. How do you draw a value given a pdf?

Edit: I found that I can use rejection sampling. But it seems complicated.
Is this correct?

```
samples <- numeric(0)

for (i in 1:36) {
  reject <- TRUE
  while (reject) {
    y <- runif(1, 4.02, 5.8)
    u <- runif(1)
    if (u < kde(y)/10/dunif(y)) {
      samples[i] <- y
      reject <- FALSE
    }
  }
}

samples
```

Comment: Are you obliged to use this density estimate, or can you use another one?

Comment: Yes I am supposed to use this density estimate.